# error in git push over http?

Tags: git, http

I have set up a git server over http, and i am able to successfully clone or pull from the http server, but when i give a git push, i am getting the following error

```
  Fetching remote heads...
 refs/
 refs/tags/
 refs/heads/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
from bc6087dffe872999105c79e8b4bdb34d3a5b7bce
to   90e7a617d575f82060c587badc0740733131266c
sending 2 objects
MKCOL 9d815311716ad694266a0cff2f17205aa12ee87c failed, aborting (22/403)
MKCOL 90e7a617d575f82060c587badc0740733131266c failed, aborting (22/403)
Updating remote server info
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Can we perform a git push over http, or http can be used only for read access ? or can it be used for write access also ?

I have Web DAV on, do i have to make any other changes to be able to perform a git push ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use WebDAV.  Set up your HTTP server to be a [smart HTTP server](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/04/smart-http.html).

If you're using Apache and have `git` installed in `/usr`, then you can add this to your `httpd.conf`:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT [path_to_git_repo_root]
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

Comment: Be aware that on other systems, the git-http-backend script may be in a different location